# How do I find comparable benchmarks between LG G4's processor and Xeon x5675

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

My friend said that a modern phone's CPU will be more powerful than an old PC's CPU.

So to test, I have a Qualcomm Snapdragon 808 processor in my LG G4 phone.

My PC has a Xeon x5675 processor, which is over 5 years old.

How can I find comparable benchmarks? Sites such as CPUBoss only seem to have benchmarks for desktop CPUs.

Comment: While their GHz ratings might be similar desktop processors have much higher IPS (instructions per second) counts due to the fact that they have more complicated cores, larger instruction sets and larger caches. Phone CPUs are about efficiency, desktop processors are about performance.

Comment: Additionally product, service or learning material recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second) and sort the table by  `Instructions per clock cycle per core (IPS / clock cycles per second / cores)` You'll notice that a 2011 Exynos has an IPS of 3.5, which is better than a 2006 Pentium III 3.4 which means that if they were clocked the same then the Exynos would win, but there's more to an overall system than IPS. Phone processors certainly are better than *very old* processors, but the comparisons are rarely relevant.